# result is not coming in a call back function

Tags: node.js

i have following code

```
parseBookmark(user_id, category_ids,bookmark_url,function(err, result) {
                console.log("PArse Rersult is " +JSON.stringify(result));
               //output is undefined here
        });

function parseBookmark(user_id, category_ids,bookmark_url,callback) {

saveBookmark(user_id,category_ids,title,bookmark_url,function(err, result) {
    //result is coming here
    callback(result);
});

}
```

Why my output is coming undefined here. Any suggestion please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change the `saveBookmark` call to:

```
saveBookmark(user_id,category_ids,title,bookmark_url,function(err, result) {
    callback(err, result);
});
```

If I understand your code correctly what you console log the second time is the `err` variable, which is `undefined`.